# How can I make my flyback converter discharge immediately?

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback

I'm using a flyback converter (220-100V to 19vdc) to power an electronics unit. But it doesn't discharge fast enough, this causes some relays to stay energised for a second or two after power supply is cut off which is not ideal.
Any ideas on how to make the flyback converter discharge almost instantly?

Also, what can cause a relay to stay energised after supply is out?

Comment: It has a big capacitor in it, right? The flyback part is a red herring, the capacitor is what stores the energy.

Answer (score 2):

> this causes some relays to stay energised for a second or two after power supply is cut off which is not ideal. ... what can cause a relay to stay energised after supply is out?

Relay coils have **pick up** and **release** voltage ratings. Most relays can pick up at 75% of rated coil voltage and can remain until the coil voltage drops down to even 30%.

The converter's output capacitors are calculated according to the max load of the converter. If the load (your circuit) draws way lower current than this rating then it will take more time for the output capacitors to discharge after power-off.

The quickest solution, as @syntax has suggested in his/her answer, can be placing dummy loads across the output of the converter. This, however, will increase the power dissipation of the system.

One solution I have used in one of my designs is to put a "discharger" which is activated after power off:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYZqdo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above diagram, the dummy load is connected to the output through the NC (normally closed) contacts. Once the circuit (and thus the RLY1) is energized the relay's contacts change position and the dummy load disconnects from the load. Once the power is cut off (and thus the RLY1 is de-energized) the dummy load re-connects to the output and discharges the output capacitors quickly. Of course, there may be excessive heat, but for a short time.

Comment: The flyback actually energizes the relay, but according to ur schematic it doesn't. And the contacts of the relay switches 220vac mains

Comment: can the dummy load be placed directly across the flyback output without using the relay contacts because I'm energizing more than one relay

Comment: @Antoine look at the schematic carefully. The RLY1 does not symbolize your relay. It's from one of my designs and is actually a part of the discharger unit that activates the discharge load. And **it does not switch the 220Vac mains**.

Comment: @Antoine If you place the dummy load directly across the output then it'll dissipate energy (which in turn shows itself as heat) continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Stored magnetic flux in the coils of the relay could take time to discharge, like any inductor. This is probably compounded with the energy stored in the coils of your flyback converter. I can imagine that a pull down resistor could potentially reduce the discharge time at the expense of dissipated energy. Perhaps there's some way to make an active circuit that drives the system to discharge faster? I don't think there is any super simple way to solve this problem. (I'm still learning so forgive me if I get anything wrong)