# What could cause a relay not to release immediately?

Tags: circuit-design, relay, electromagnetic

I have got a relay that doesn't release immediately after power is cut off. What could be the possible causes of this?

Comment: Schematic needed. How did you hook it up, and what is the model number of the relay?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the relay type, link to datasheet, voltage AC/DC, what is switching it, is there a snubber and what the measured release time actually is compared with specification.

Comment: One of the 101 reason is that you wrongly use NC, instead of NO.

Comment: 1. maybe if you are leaving your relay coil pins open after energizing it and there is no flyback diode then its the coil energy itself. But for an actual cause, you need to provide the circuit diagram.

Comment: I've [already answered](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524654/how-can-i-make-my-flyback-converter-discharge-immediately/524666#524666) this in your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524654/how-can-i-make-my-flyback-converter-discharge-immediately).

Comment: @Deepak, having no flyback diode will give the shortest release time. Adding any kind of snubbing will slow it down. A snubber diode maximises the delay.

Comment: @Transistor can you please tell how. I am curious to learn.

Comment: @Deepak think about where the energy that flows through the diode comes from.

Comment: Are there any **supply decoupling capacitors** in your circuit? When these are large enough, they can power the circuit (and the relay) for a short time (up to a few seconds) after you disconnect the power. What makes you think that a relay will disengage **immediately** after the power is cut? A relay is a **mechanical device** so it will need some time to disengage.

Comment: @Deepak, create a simple CircuitLab circuit with a DC PSU, time delay switch and an inductor, run the simulator on it and monitor the current. Try it open-circuit, with a resistor, a diode and a Zener diode (with a voltage higher than the supply). Then try a bit of calculus to work out the discharge time as a function of snubber resistance and then find where this maximises.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not understanding that when you disconnect the relay the energy is still in it and dissipating in form of energy required to hold spring of relay?

Comment: @Transistor ok it will try it and see what happens.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Relays never open ‘immediately’ there is always a delay, usually hundreds of microseconds to several milliseconds, depending on the relay construction and how the stored energy is dealt with.

Possible reasons for a relay not opening include problems in the driver circuit (coil current not falling to essentially zero), contacts sticking (typically a result of damage due to excessive inrush current or a momentary short) and debris within the relay (very unusual).

For example, omitting the flyback diode can result in exceeding the safe operating area of the driver, causing cumulative damage and eventual increase in ‘off’ current to the point where the relay may not drop out reliably.

Sticking contacts can manifest as the relay remaining closed until it is tapped mechanically.

Comment: OP had asked [the same question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524654/how-can-i-make-my-flyback-converter-discharge-immediately) with different words.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  you can flag the question as a duplicate if you think it is so.

Answer (score -1):

A relay consists of a soft iron core on which a coil is wound. When the coil is energized a magnetic field is generated thus magnetizing the soft iron core which pulls the spring-loaded armature. This movement closes or opens the contacts. Since the coil is basically an inductor It does not allow the current to die down quickly when the coil is de-energized and the relay drops off with a delay of a few milliseconds. However, sometimes due to residual magnetism of the core and weak spring attached to the armature, the armature may not fall back after de-energizing the coil and a mechanical tapping may release it.

A reverse-biased diode across the coil helps to reduce the delay.